# CPU overheating in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cpu, overheating, temperature, intel-cpu

As I was checking the kernel logs I noticed :

**kernel: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 13430)**.

I have 4 CPUs and all of them have the same issue.
My laptop hardware info :

K46CB (ASUS-NotebookSKU)

CPU info :

1. Architecture: x86_64
2. Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz

I searched the log and found this [CPU hardware errors in Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941686/cpu-hardware-errors-in-ubuntu-17-04)
 and [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating), I checked my packages and I have **thermald** and **intel-microcode** installed.

I can hear my laptop's fan working, but sometimes it really gets hot and I can feel it through the case.

In Windows-10, although CPU usage gets high, the temperature is usually normal.

Any idea what may have gone wrong? and what can I do to further investigate this issue?

#### Update

I checked **thermald.service** status and I found this line :

**thermald[879]:sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state**

Answer (score 3):

You should see (and possibly subscribe to) this bug report:

- [Thermald sysfs read failed /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zoneX/temp](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1764320)

There have been numerous posts in **Ask Ubuntu** about CPU throttling recently:

- [Core/Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled - Lenovo E590](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144129/core-package-temperature-above-threshold-cpu-clock-throttled-lenovo-e590)
- [Set CPU temperature throttle threshold on Ubuntu/Thinkpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013225/set-cpu-temperature-throttle-threshold-on-ubuntu-thinkpad)
- [XPS 9370 thermal throttling ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040015/xps-9370-thermal-throttling-ubuntu-18-04/1051025)

All these posts say the same thing which happens to me periodically:

```
~$ journalctl | grep 'cpu clock throttled'
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 22 10:55:52 alien kernel: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
```

In my case it happens so rarely and with no adverse side-effects I've chosen to ignore the errors.

Similar launchpad bug reports on the same issue:

- [Erratic behavior of CPU frequency control under load](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1797802)
- [Kernel wrong temperature reporting](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1781924)

And just so you know it's not just Ubuntu, from Redhat:

- [Overheating CPU generates Hardware Error messages](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1373881)

Comment: What thermal/fan control packages do you have installed? If thermald is one of them, have you customized /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml for your hardware configuration?

Comment: @heynnema I've never used software to control the fans. I do use `thermald` but it has default config file. Fans are controlled by the laptop and almost never come on. I have to do something silly like run all 8 CPUs at 100% for more about a minute.

Comment: See my answer for a brief intro on how to develop a custom .xml file to control thermald. It's not that difficult. You can also search AU for other thermald answers that I've provided in the past. I've got thermald keeping my temps < 140 degrees.

Comment: @heynnema I don't have any temperature problems since May 20 the errors only appeared once in `journalctl`. I like the way the Laptop's ACPI keeps the fans turned off all the time. *No noise is good noise*. Conky reports temp at 51 / 52 degrees as I type this now.

Comment: Nice. Hey, point of note... you and I used to have similar rep, but you've blown way beyond me now. How much time do you dedicate to AU help?

Comment: @heynnema I'm learning Linux and Bash so I actually get more help here than I give out. Developing software requires (for me at least) a lot of solutions found in **Ask Ubuntu**, **Stack Overflow** and **Unix & Linux** sites. As for amount of time an hour every morning before work and a couple / few hours after work. Weekends fluctuate depending on well the weekend :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` file needs to be tweaked for your hardware...

<strike>I'd install `thermald`...</strike>

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install thermald

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are. Many of the answers come from me.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Answer (score 0):

The problem is threefold. First, you have high CPU usage. Secondly, the CPU's cooling is not enough. Third, it doesn't correctly throttle.

**Higher CPU usage** might be due to Unity not correctly using your hardware acceleration; and Unity is quite CPU-intensive. You might tweak it or even switch to a different desktop manager such as: Cinnamon, Kubuntu, Lubuntu or Linux Mint.

**CPU Cooling** on laptops is notoriously bad. CleanIng your fan and putting the laptop on a flat surface instead of fabric/pillow might help.

About **throttling**, you can set the maximum CPU frequency to a lower setting or switch to power saving mode.

Answer (score 0):

update your 'thermald' to 2.4.8 the latest one.
https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon/tree/v2.4.8

run 'thermald --version' to determine your version.

reason.. many, many thermald bugs and workarounds for intel 7700 cpus etc..
https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon/issues/293
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1600599

Comment: The links info may help but what about later when the links are gone? If the info in the links is helpful include it in the answer not just links.